# How to send ad hoc proactive event

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

How do I sent an event proactive message to all agents?

I can successfully send a plain text message to all agents, but I would prefer to send an event instead.

Here is my attempt:

```
            //Create a new message for sending an event
            var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity() as Activity;                    

            var conversationId = agent.conversationId;
            message.ChannelId = agent.channelId;


            // Set the address-related properties in the message and send the message.
            message.From = botAccount;
            message.Recipient = agentAccount;
            message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount() { Id = conversationId };

            //Type.Event/backchannel approach
            message.Type = ActivityTypes.Event;
            message.Name = "newCustomerOnHoldAlert";
            message.Value = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(customerEmail);
            await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```

Here is the counterpart javascript:

```
                    botConnection.activity$
                        .filter(activity => activity.type === "event")
                        .subscribe(activity => doActivity(activity));

                    function doActivity(activity) {
                        console.log(activity.name);
                        switch (activity.name) {
                            case "newCustomerOnHoldAlert":
                                console.log("in newCustomerOnHoldAlert")
                                break;

                            default:
                                console.log("doActivity() did nothing.")
                                break;
                        }
                    }
```

This is related to [my previous question about how to intercept receiving proactive messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724615/intercept-receiving-messages). I would like to explore both options.

Comment: What do you mean by "send an event"  can you please explain this in detail.  Also, are we assuming that "all agents" have already started a conversation with the bot.  If they have not previously spoken with the bot you will not be able to do this.

Comment: @JasonSowers I meant send and Activity with ActivityTypes.Event; yes, they have already spoken with the bot to signify that they are available or logged in. I wanted the sent event to trigger a UI change on the Agent's side.

Comment: I think this is because you are using `var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity() as Activity;` instead of  `var message = Activity.CreateEventActivity() as Activity;`

Comment: Does the code you've shared not work?  What happens exactly?

Comment: @JasonSowers I replaced my code with `CreateEventActivity()` but the behavior is the same.

Comment: @EricDahlvang what happens is the javascript is not triggered at all after the proactive event message is sent. not even `console.log(activity.name)`. but if i change the Activity from Event to Message, the messages are sent to the agents. so I know part of it is working right. and normal Events are also working fine...

Comment: It took a loooooong time but I finally figured it out: the problem was in my botAccount and agentAccount variables. I was saving those information in Azure Table. I was saving the wrong information - switched some From and To values. So both messaged and events now working fine for me. Thank you for making me feel like it should work so I stuck to it :)